# Can I speak HTTP/2 over STDIN/STDOUT?

Tags: http2, nghttp2

Can I speak HTTP/2 over STDIN/STDOUT?  If so, how could I do it, and what would be the limitations?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: @BarryPollard To communicate using HTTP with a local program on Windows, which doesn't have Unix sockets until Windows 10

Comment: Ok but curious as to why you think HTTP (and especially HTTP/2) would be the best protocol for this rather than something (anything?) else?

Comment: @BarryPollard Because I want to proxy a server over a single stream?  There are many possibilities — a (hypothetical) idea for running web apps as desktop apps being just one of them.  Another is proxying Docker’s control socket over qrexec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking [HTTP/2 does by definition require a TCP connection](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#starting):

> An HTTP/2 connection is an application-layer protocol running on top of a TCP connection ([TCP]). The client is the TCP connection initiator.
>
> HTTP/2 uses the same "http" and "https" URI schemes used by HTTP/1.1. HTTP/2 shares the same default port numbers: 80 for "http" URIs and 443 for "https" URIs. As a result, implementations processing requests for target resource URIs like http://example.org/foo or https://example.com/bar are required to first discover whether the upstream server (the immediate peer to which the client wishes to establish a connection) supports HTTP/2

That being said you probably could adapt the protocol to be used over any arbitrary transport (like pipes), but as far as I know there's no software that currently works that way. If libraries like that did exist I'd expect to see it in test suites for HTTP/2 libraries. Here's a site [containing a list of HTTP/2 test applications](https://blog.cloudflare.com/tools-for-debugging-testing-and-using-http-2/). It's possible one of these may have a mode similar to what you're looking for.

As far as advantages and limitations go, since HTTP/2 wasn't designed to be used this way, I'm not sure there's much advantage in any case. The primary limitation is the same: that most software wouldn't be able to work with pipes.